# Numpy - Product of Cartesian Product Along Last Axis of Jagged Array

Tags: python, numpy, tensor, cartesian-product, jagged-arrays

Given a nested list with unequal number of elements, I would like to find the fastest way to calculate the product of the cartesian product along the last axis. In other words, first calculate the cartesian product between all sublists, then find the multiplicative product along all combinations. Then finally, I want to insert those values into a matrix of the same size/dimensionality as the original input. As an added piece of complexity, I want to pad axes of shape `(1, )` with an extra 0. For example:

```
example1 = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5], [6], [7]]
```

should result in

```
[[[[[ 630.    0.]
    [   0.    0.]]
   [[   0.    0.]
    [   0.    0.]]]
  [[[ 840.    0.]
    [   0.    0.]]
   [[   0.    0.]
    [   0.    0.]]]]
 [[[[1260.    0.]
    [   0.    0.]]
   [[   0.    0.]
    [   0.    0.]]]
  [[[1680.    0.]
    [   0.    0.]]
   [[   0.    0.]
    [   0.    0.]]]]]
```

which has a shape `(2, 2, 2, 2, 2)`, although it would be `(2, 2, 1, 1, 1)` without padding.

My initial function is:

```
def convert_nest_to_product_tensor(nest):

    # find indices to collect elements from
    combinations = list(itertools.product(*[range(len(l)) for l in nest]))

    # collect elements and then calculate product for every Cartesian product
    products = np.array(
        [np.product([nest[i][idx] for i, idx in enumerate(comb)]) for comb in combinations]
        )

    # pad tensor for axes of shape 1
    tensor_shape = [len(l) for l in nest]
    tensor_shape = tuple([axis_shape+1 if axis_shape==1 else axis_shape for axis_shape in tensor_shape])
    tensor = np.zeros(tensor_shape)

    # insert values
    for i, idx in enumerate(combinations):
        tensor[idx] = products[i]

    return tensor
```

However, it takes while, specifically the part where I find the product of the Cartesian products. I tried replacing that component using `np.meshgrid` + `np.stack`:

```
products = np.stack(np.meshgrid(*nest), axis=-1).reshape(-1, len(nest))
products = np.prod(products, axis=-1)
```

and while I get the correct values much faster, but they are not in the correct output order:

```
[[[[[ 630.    0.]
    [   0.    0.]]
   [[   0.    0.]
    [   0.    0.]]]
  [[[1260.    0.]
    [   0.    0.]]
   [[   0.    0.]
    [   0.    0.]]]]
 [[[[ 840.    0.]
    [   0.    0.]]
   [[   0.    0.]
    [   0.    0.]]]
  [[[1680.    0.]
    [   0.    0.]]
   [[   0.    0.]
    [   0.    0.]]]]]
```

Any feedback on how to make this work (quickly) is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

A simple way of getting the cartesian tuples and product:

```
In [10]: alist = list(itertools.product(*example1))
In [11]: alist
Out[11]: [(1, 3, 5, 6, 7), (1, 4, 5, 6, 7), (2, 3, 5, 6, 7), (2, 4, 5, 6, 7)]
In [12]: [np.prod(x) for x in alist]
Out[12]: [630, 840, 1260, 1680]
```

Or use `math.prod` for a no-numpy solution.